# Get the total number of pages in a report using Report Viewer

Tags: crystal-reports, report, viewer

How do I get total number pages in a report using Report Viewer?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are using?

```
=Globals!TotalPages
```

be aware that this only works in the header or footer of the report.

Also, in reporting services 2008 the report may be rendered a page at a time on demand as each page is viewed, and the TotalPages number may not be accurate until the entire report has been viewed/rendered.